# Threads join() a thread more than once

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to make two threads work `simultaneous`. The first one should increment a value each second, and print that value to screen. The second one, should, each time a value is incremented, ask for some input value, and than print that value.

When I run my code, the incrementation goes well, but the `stdin` just ask me for an input once, and than it simple doesn't go on the repeater.join() nevermore (but it goes in Try).

My main thread:

```
public class mainThread extends Thread
  {
    //global variables
public int contador=0;
public int maxcont=10;

public void incContador()
{
    this.contador++;
}

public void run()
{   
    Thread repeater = (new Thread(new repeatThread()));
    repeater.start();
    for(int i=0; i<maxcont; i++)
    {
        incContador();
        try{
            //It's asked to increment 1 unit each second
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }catch(InterruptedException e){System.out.println("Deu erro!\n");}

        System.out.println(contador);
        try{
            //use my other thread
            repeater.join();
        }catch(InterruptedException e){System.out.println("Deu erro 2!\n");}
    }
} 



public static void main(String[] args)
{
    (new mainThread()).start();
}

}
```

My repeater thread

```
   public class repeatThread implements Runnable
   {
public void run()
{
    BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String s = "";
        try{
            s = buf.readLine();  
            System.out.println("Input is: "+s);

        }
        catch(IOException e){System.out.println("MyThreadRepeater - readLine() method error");}
    }




public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    (new Thread(new repeatThread())).start();
}
}
```

Comment: There are several problems here. First, the `run` method of `Runnable` is called **once**; nothing is magically going to call it in a loop. It's not supposed to return until the thread is done. So you need a loop in your `repeatThread`'s `run` method. Second, it makes no sense to `join` a thread more than once, because the `join` call doesn't return until the thread *has finished*, completely. Calling `join` on a dead thread will just return immediately. Your whole approach will need to be changed. If you want inter-thread cooperation, consider learning about the concept of a "semaphore."

Comment: This is a practise exercise asked in a Currency Class i'm having at university. It's only possible to use join(), start(), Thread() and sleep() methods.
This is not the original exercise, it has a slight change from my part, but the original asks me to create a thread that increments a counter while another thread repeats the stdin to stdout. Can u give me some ints how to do it just using that methods ? (it's not as evalutaion method, just learning myself this and studying to finals)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you've misunderstand what `Thread#join()` does. this line

```
repeater.join();
```

blocks the current thread you're executing in, and waits for the thread represented by the `repeater` `Thread` to end.

Your `repeater` `Thread` is using a `repeatThread` object which simply asks for input once and ends.

Why would you expect it to prompt more input from the user?

Comment: Okay, i got it. So a thread only can run full once, after that it's a "dead thread". How could i fix this to ask me for a input each time the counter (contador) is incremented ?

Comment: @Duozhasht Use some kind of notification pattern, ie. observer or callback.

Answer (score 0):

I did not get your question completely. But your repeater code only executes the

```
BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String s = "";
        try{
            s = buf.readLine();  
            System.out.println("Input is: "+s);

        }
        catch(IOException e){System.out.println("MyThreadRepeater - readLine() method error");}
    }
```

code only once. Run it inside a loop to run it continuously.

Comment: I tested with a cycle already, but i don't know how to get back to my main thread just with join(),sleep(),Thread() and start() methods.

Answer (score 0):

Your repeatThread runs only once. You MUST create new repeatThread object every iteration if you don't want to chang it's code. I mean like:

```
public void run()
{   
    for(int i=0; i<maxcont; i++)
    {
        Thread repeater = (new Thread(new repeatThread()));
        repeater.start();
        incContador();
        try{
            //It's asked to increment 1 unit each second
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }catch(InterruptedException e){System.out.println("Deu erro!\n");}

        System.out.println(contador);
        try{
            //use my other thread
            repeater.join();
        }catch(InterruptedException e){System.out.println("Deu erro 2!\n");}
    }
}
```

You'd better use Barriers (ex. CyclicBarrier) when you need several threads to wait each other at specific point. I should also mention that Thread.sleep(1000); may keep thread sleeping AT LEAST for a second, but not exactly.